# MySql table type, how do I draw column data from one table to another automatically?

Tags: mysql

I have a 2 tables called 'members' and 'users' that both have 2 columns: name & gender. I want that everytime I add a new 'name' to members table, the value in 'gender' column in that row would be updated from 'users' table:

```
**users:**
Emilia - F
John - M
David - M
**members:**
Synthia - F

'INSERT INTO members VALUES('David')...or whatever'
now **members:**
Synthia - F
David - M
```

Comment: Physically storing the same data (the gender column) in two different tables goes against the normalization principle of relational databases and may lead to data corruption (assume that at some point the value in users is modified by the copy stored in members is not, that could be even more confusing than your users having sex changes to begin with ^_^)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an [insert trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html). However you should not have a copy of the gender in two different tables - it breaks normalization, requires more storage space and risks that the two copies will get out of sync.

Instead you should use a foreign key and join the tables when you need information from both. You can use the username as the foreign key, or the autoincrement id, if you have one.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're talking about a computed column, but I'm not sure if MySQL supports them (google a bit, I could be wrong). Why not create a view over the two tables instead? You could try something like...

```
CREATE VIEW MemberDetail
AS
  SELECT mem.Name,
    usr.Gender
  FROM Members mem
  INNER JOIN Users usr ON mem.Name = usr.Name;
```

Comment: MySQL supports views (but not materialized views) since 5.0

Answer (score 0):

how about [INSERT ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) syntax?

```
INSERT into members (name, gender) 
SELECT u.name, u.gender FROM users u WHERE u.name='Cynthia';
```